# Is there any way to check Rewrited URL in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

In my Project i don't want to show query string values to users. For that case i used URL Rewriting in asp.net. So my URL Looks like below.

> `http://localhost/test/default.aspx?id=1`

to

> `http://localhost/test/general.aspx`

The first URL will be rewrites to second URL, but it will still executes the default.aspx page with that query string value. This is working fine.

But my question is that, is there any way the user can find that original URL in browser?

Comment: Take Firebug or anything else and look the network traffic. You'll easily see if your config is correct for your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured answer for my question. We can easily found the rewritten urls. If we saw the view source of that page in browser then we can see that original url with querystring values.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no.

The browser can't tell what actual script ended up servicing the request - it only knows what it sent to the server (unless the server issued a redirect, but then the browser would make a new request to the redirect target).

Comment: Well, there is a way, if he write it down inside the page, the original url and use it on a java script to show it to the user some how. With out that of course there is no way.

Answer (score 0):

Since URL rewriting takes an incoming request and routes it to a different resource, I believe the answer is yes. Somewhere in your web traffic you are requesting `http://localhost/test/default.aspx?id=1` and it is being rewritten as the new request `http://localhost/test/general.aspx`.

While this may hide the original request from displaying in the browser, at some point it did send that original URL as an HTTP GET.

As suggested, use Firebug or Fiddler to sniff the traffic.

Comment: The translation (re-write) is done on server transparent from the browser and the user.

Comment: Yes, but the *browser* sent the request, so it is discoverable. It may take some work to find, but any of the browser debug tools will show you it is there.

Comment: the browser send the `http://localhost/test/general.aspx` the translate to `http://localhost/test/default.aspx?id=1` is not discovery

Comment: As stated in the question, you have it backwards. The browser requests `http://localhost/test/default.aspx?id=1` and it gets rewritten to `http://localhost/test/general.aspx`.

Comment: I do not think that this is was stated in the question, and this is not the definition of re-write, this is a redirect.

Comment: "The first URL will be rewrites to second URL", as stated in the OP.

Comment: yes the first rewrite to the second, the second is the one that is show on the browser. The first is "rewrite", is not exist any more.

Comment: But the first URL is the original request, as made by the browser. It **is** discoverable.

Comment: look: If the browser sends A, then the A stays and rewriten on server on B. The B is transparent and you can not see it except if the user write it on the browser return inside the html. If the browser sends A, and then you see B on the url then its a redirect (not a rewrite).

Comment: You are arguing that OP is doing the rewrite wrong, I get that. OP says he wants to hide the query string, and is doing a rewrite of `default.aspx?id=1` in order to hide the id parameter. I'm saying if you are requesting `default.aspx?id=1` and rewrite it to `general.aspx`, you are not really hiding it. That is how the question is phrased.